# Retrieve image path from back end and display the image in angular html template throws unsafe error

Tags: spring-boot, angular8

Hi guys on my code I'm retrieving an image path from back end and I set that path in src attribute.[src]="image path" I thought this will display the image but instead in browser console it shows a warning :sanitizing unsafe URL value :
and an error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME unsafe:
I use angular for the front end and spring for the backend.
my HTML is as follows
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCBN1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your component:

```js
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizationService) {}
```

and the following to your template:

```html
<img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imgSrcProperty)"/>
```

Where `imgSrcProperty` is the offending image base64 encoded.